# How to Add external Javascript and CSS for CakePhp

Tags: javascript, css, cakephp

I am new to CakePhp. I want to get the help of the external javascript and css files. I have downloaded those files. And included those files in **webroot** directory (js and css sub directories). So If I want to use those in a view.ctp how can I call them. Can you explain me simply ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake is still PHP. You must add link do css in `head` of html file (.ctp view file).

There are two ways, write `link` tag with `rel` and `src` attributes or using `HtmlHelper`

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the HTML helper like so :

```
  print $this->Html->css("name_of_css_file");
  print $this->Html->script("name_of_javascript_file");
```

So long as you not doing anything crazy and are using the default ".css" and ".js" extensions - you can leave out the extensions from the above code.